# Is there a flag for :s[ubstitute] in Vim that will not save the pattern?

Tags: regex, vim, substitution

I'm trying to create an `autocmd` that will replace all the whitespaces in the file when I exit the insert mode. However, AFAIK that would make Vim remember the pattern and remove what was already in there.

```
" Add function for remove tailing whitespaces
command! CleanupTrailingSpaces :%s/\s\+$//ge | :nohlsearch
autocmd InsertLeave * :CleanupTrailingSpaces
```

Is there a flag for `:s[ubstitute]` that will make it not saving the pattern?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Such a flag would be useful, but does not yet exist. However, you can save and reset the register like this:

```
" Add function for remove tailing whitespaces
command! CleanupTrailingSpaces let reset = @/ | %s/\s\+$//ge | let @/ = reset | nohlsearch
autocmd InsertLeave * :CleanupTrailingSpaces
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! I actually forgot about `@` register. That should work. ;)

Answer (score 3):

I got something similar from [vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/tidying-whitespace/). :-)

```
function! <SID>StripTrailingWhitespaces()
    " Preparation: save last search, and cursor position.
    let _s=@/
    let l = line(".")
    let c = col(".")
    " Do the business:
    %s/\s\+$//e
    " Clean up: restore previous search history, and cursor position
    let @/=_s
    call cursor(l, c)
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> <F5> :call <SID>StripTrailingWhitespaces()<CR>
autocmd BufWritePre *.py,*.js :call <SID>StripTrailingWhitespaces()
```